# Second order differential equation, with term from previous numerical solution

Tags: differential-equations, broken-code

I have a second order differential equation, in terms of a term that was previously obtained from numerically solving another equation.

Numerical solution of equation before 2nd order equation:

```
Rgas = Rationalize[8.314]; (* gas constant *)
acoef[tc_, pc_] := (27*Rgas^2*tc^2)/(64*pc);
bcoef[tc_, pc_] := (Rgas*tc)/(8*pc);
Clear[p, t];
latentK = 76.9*10^3*39*1.67*10^-27*6.022*10^23;
tcK = 2223; (* Kelvin *)
pcK = 16*10^6; (*Pa *)

eqn = (p - Rgas*t)*v^3 - bcoef[tcK, pcK]*p*v^2 + acoef[tcK, pcK]*v - acoef[tcK, pcK]*bcoef[tcK, pcK];
asolns = Solve[eqn == 0, v] ;
(eqn /. asolns)[[1]] ;
realroot = v /. asolns[[1]];
```

And now, my 2nd order differential equation, in terms of `realroot`, which is a function of p(t) an t:

```
NDSolve[p''[t] == latentK/(t*realroot), p[t], t]
```

But this is not working.
I guess one of the problems is that `realroot` is not defined to be a function of p(t) and t...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues need to be addressed.  First, boundary conditions need to be specified for `NDSolve`.  Second, `p` needs to be replaced by `p[t]` in `realroot`.  In the absence of boundary conditions specified in the Question, I have provide some sample expressions.

```
s = NDSolve[{p''[t] == latentK/(t*realroot /. p -> p[t]), p[1] == 1, 
    p'[1] == 0}, p[t], {t, 1, 2}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[p[t] /. s, {t, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: @SuperCiocia In response to your comment, now deleted, `Plot[Re[p[t]] /. First@s, {t, 273, 293}]` will provide a curve, as will `Plot[Im[p[t]] /. First@s, {t, 273, 293}]`, but the results suggests an error in your equations.